# Showing $(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} [ (1+i) i^n + (1-i)(-i)^n]$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to show following equation holds. 
\begin{align}
(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} [ (1+i) i^n + (1-i)(-i)^n]
\end{align}
Can you give some hint or any practical method to compute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$$
a_n=hr^n+ks^n
$$
with $r\ne s$. The sequence satisfies the recursion
$$
a_{n+2}-(r+s)a_{n+1}+rsa_n=0
$$
with initial values
$$
a_0=h+k,\quad a_1=hr+ks
$$
In the case where $r=i$ and $s=-i$, the recursion is $a_{n+2}=-a_n$. The initial values, for $h=(1+i)/2$ and $k=(1-i)/2$ are
$$
a_0=1,\quad a_1=-1
$$
So your sequence is
$$
1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,\dotsc
$$
and $a_n=(-1)^{(n-1)(n-2)/2}=(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$ satisfies the requirement.

Comment: I think that this is the best perspective here.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the real part of $(1+i)i^n$.

Solution:

> The LHS is $-Re((1+i)i^n)$. Now $i^n=1,i,-1,-i,\dots$ is a periodic sequence of period $4$. So, $-Re((1+i)i^n)$ is $-1,1,1,-1,\dots$ is also a periodic sequence of period $4$. The RHS is that same sequence.

Comment: I'd like to see a solution where $(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}$ appears naturally.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually four possibilities:

If $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ of $4k+2$ then it is $1=1$. If $n$ is of the form $4k+3$ of $4k+0$ then it is $-1=-1$.